# writing a median function

Tags: python, median

i am trying to write a median function, currently i have one that takes a list and sorts it and then gives the median. but i am trying to rewrite it so that if the list has an even number of elements it doesnt print the median but rather the 2 numbers from the list that the median is between. heres my code

```
def getMedian(A):
    A=sorted(A)
    n=len(A)
    m=n-1
    return (A[int(n/2)]+A[int(m/2)])/2

def main():
    myList=[3,5,9,3,11]
    print(getMedian(myList))
    myList=[3,9,11,5]
    print(getMedian(myList))
main()
```

currently it outputs 5 and then 7 but im trying to get it to output 5 and then 5,9 any advice?

Comment: You told it to return the average of the 2 middle numbers at the end of your function. I suggest checking if n%2 == 0 or n%2 ==1 and then have an if-then statement to determine what is returned

Comment: And what to return for `[5,10,10,15]`?

Answer (score 1):

import statistics

statistics.median(data)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the list has an odd number of elements and then change the return value(s) accordingly:

```
def getMedian(A):
    A = sorted(A)
    n = len(A)
    m = n-1
    if n%2 == 1:
        return (A[int(n/2)]+A[int(m/2)])/2
    else:
        return A[int(m/2)], A[int(n/2)]

def main():
    myList = [3,5,9,3,11]
    print(getMedian(myList))
    myList = [3,9,11,5]
    print(getMedian(myList))

main()
```

Output:

```
>>> 
5
(5, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of doing it.

```
def getMedian(A):
    A.sort()
    mid = len(A) // 2
    return [[A[~mid], A[mid]], (A[mid] + A[~mid]) / 2][len(A) % 2]


def main():
    myList = [3, 5, 9, 3, 11]
    print(getMedian(myList))
    myList = [3, 9, 11, 5]
    print(getMedian(myList))


main()
```

output

```
5.0
[5, 9]
```